# Remove Frames With FFmpegFrameRecorder

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, record, javacv

I'm trying to record a video in Android using the JavaCV lib. My problem is, I am trying to make something like touch to record project. But I want user to be able to delete the frames.

So my question is, **how I can remove last 10 seconds that I record with FFmpegFrameRecorder ?**

Comment: so u got any solution yet ?

Comment: Nope I could not find...